# Need to add an alias to a list of results generated by Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rails-models

Forgive my vague topic, I am currently working on a rails application with three models User, list and items. The user has many lists and a list can have many items. I am currently working on a method that shows the number of lists that a user has and I need the list to be able to give me the number of items in it. I believe that there is a way of parsing this data without me having to create column items in the list model. Forgive me as I am new to rails I am sure there's a pretty simple way of doing this. Below is the syntax for my method and also the class list and items. Thanks in advance. (i am just trying to get the number of items in each list to be parsed out in the list data)

```
def showLists
     pageSize = 10
     pageNum = 1
     if (params[:limit])
       pageSize = (params[:limit])
       pageSize = pageSize.to_i
     end
     pageNum= (params[:page]) 
     pageNum = pageNum.to_i   
     @key = PrivateKey.find(1)
     @key = @key.key     
     if (params[:apiKey]) == @key 
      @user = User.find_by_facebookexternalId(params[:id])
      if @user.access_key.key == (params[:accessToken])         
         y =(pageSize*pageNum)
         x =(y-pageSize) 
         @list = @user.lists 
         total= @list.count
         @list = @list.all(:select=>[:name,:id,:listtype,:description ], :include=>[:items=>@list[x].items.count])    
         @list = @list[x .. y] 
         #listResponse={:name=>@list.name}        
         response = {:total =>total,:page => pageNum, :limit=> pageSize, :userId=> @user.id, :accessToken=> @user.access_key.key , :list=>@list } 
         #response = {:lists => @list}
         respond_to do |format|
           format.json {render :json  => response}
         end
      end        
     end
   end
```

schema information

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: lists
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  name        :string(255)
#  active      :boolean
#  user_id     :integer
#  listtype    :string(255)
#  description :text
#  roughlist   :boolean
#  created_at  :datetime         not null
#  updated_at  :datetime         not null
#

class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :active , :type , :description , :roughlist,  :listtype
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => :user_id
  has_many :map_list_items
  has_many :items, :through => :map_list_items
  #has_and_belongs_to_many :items

end

And my item schema is here

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: items
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  name        :string(255)
#  description :string(255)
#  user_id     :integer
#  barcode     :string(255)
#  asin_id     :string(255)
#  isbn_id     :string(255)
#  barcode_id  :integer
#  created_at  :datetime         not null
#  updated_at  :datetime         not null
#

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :barcode , :foreign_key => :barcode_id
  has_many :map_item_tags
  has_many :map_list_items
  has_many :lists, :through => :map_list_items
  #has_and_belongs_to_many :lists

end
```

A sample of the json file i get is below

```
{
    "total": 3,
    "page": 1,
    "limit": 10,
    "userId": 5,
    "accessToken": "BAAFdQiIeExEBAOwtEtFXgI0c2k9kka3EQbEBDca2FGJZBQyIOLGfnJQr7k1FaGFEx6dzzWxQkxZB4uFSEj3HvZARyZBKLtTzn9NhEXEBtsBxuPBf2O5PxtofkZC4GQg9OmWGahJ42kZBuEay68rlDb",
    "list": [
        {
            "description": "",
            "id": 1,
            "listtype": "christmas",
            "name": "mom"
        },
        {
            "description": "",
            "id": 2,
            "listtype": "christmas",
            "name": "mom"
        },
        {
            "description": "",
            "id": 3,
            "listtype": "christmas",
            "name": "mom"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use acts_as_api gem for json.
It makes making json very easy even through models.
There you can simply add your own attribures.

Comment: I need to be able to get the amount of items for every list really.. I am not bothered about the alias

Comment: using this gem you can make template for json in lists where you will put list.items.count